# Is there a LogBeta function like the LogGamma?

Tags: special-functions, logarithmic-scale

In a computation, I need `Log[Beta[alpha+j,beta-j+n]]` of some kind.

Is there a `LogBeta` function built-in to avoid any under/over flow problems?
There is one in [R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Special.html), called `lbeta(a,b)`.

I could rewrite them in terms of `Gamma` functions and thus in terms of `LogGamma`. But I am lazy. I search a bit for it, just can't seem to find it.

So *Mathematica* does not have it?

On a related matter, `Beta` sometimes gives bad results, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66410/probability-going-outside-1-due-to-optimization-violation-of-constraint).

Comment: `Beta[a,b]==Gamma[a] Gamma[b]/Gamma[a+b]` So `logBeta[a_, b_]:= LogGamma[a] + LogGamma[b] - LogGamma[a+b]`

Comment: @belisarius please post this as an answer!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Done, but not sure if it's constructive. In any case `logbeta[]` is now available when googling the site :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)

```
Beta[a,b] == Gamma[a] Gamma[b]/Gamma[a+b]
```

So we can define

```
logBeta[a_, b_]:= LogGamma[a] + LogGamma[b] - LogGamma[a+b]

GraphicsRow[ Plot3D[#@logBeta[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] & /@ {Re, Im}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What about the logarithm of the incomplete Beta function? That can't be reduced to `LogGamma`s. Just asking cause I had a similar underflow/overflow problem using `Beta` or `BetaRegularized` to compute incomplete Beta values.

Comment: @becko I haven't thought about that. The question is about the complete beta (I guess). Let me see, but it seems a different problem.

Comment: @becko, that is a much more difficult problem; the complete implementation of a polyalgorithm (algorithms valid for different domains patched together) will be needed for that.